# Nginx server redirect loop

Tags: docker, nginx, devops

after a deployment tonight my nginx server keeps getting 301 redirecting to the same URI and thus browsers won't load the site. It's a node app within a docker container with 4 containers in total: app, wordpress, redis, nginx. I am pretty sure that I didn't change anything in the nginx config within the docker project, just changed the sub project (src-folder). I even reverted all my changes back to what I had before but the issue stays.

Neither the normal URL nor the Wordpress domain is loading, it will always 301 redirect to the root.

The configuration should 301 redirect all traffic from non-SSL to SSL and render the page.

My config looks like this:

```
upstream node {
    server app:3000;
}

server {
        listen 80;
        server_name example.com www.example.com;

        return 301 https://example.com;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name wordpress.example.com;

    return 301 https://example.com;
}

server {
        listen 443;
        server_name www.example.com;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/example.com.cert;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/example.com.key;

        return 301 https://example.com;
}
server {
    listen 443 default ssl;
    server_name example.com;
    root /var/www/html/project;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/example.com.cert;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/example.com.key;

    set $isopen 0;


    location / {
        proxy_pass http://node;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding "";
        proxy_set_header Proxy "";
        expires off;
    }
    location /lp/ {
        proxy_ssl_server_name on;
        proxy_pass https://sub.example.com/folder/;
    }
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name wordpress.example.com;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/wordpress.example.com.cert;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/wordpress.example.com.key;

    error_page 397 https://$host:$server_port$request_uri;

    set $isopen 0;

    if ($request_uri ~ '^/wp-json/wp/v2/.*') {
        set $isopen 1;
    }
    if ($request_uri ~ '^/wp-includes/.*') {
        set $isopen 1;
    }
    if ($request_uri ~ '^/wp-content/.*') {
        set $isopen 1;
    }
    if ($request_uri ~ '^/wp-admin/.*') {
        set $isopen 1;
    }
    if ($request_uri ~ '^/wp-login.php') {
        set $isopen 1;
    }
    if ($request_uri ~ '^/wp-admin/.*\.(php|css|js)') {
        set $isopen 1;
    }
    if ($isopen !~ 1) {
        return 301 https://$server_name/wp-admin/;
    }

    location / {
            proxy_pass https://wordpress;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding "";
            proxy_set_header Proxy "";
            expires off;
       }
}
```

My docker containers listen to the following ports:

```
Containers statuses 
              Name                            Command               State                      Ports                    
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
project_app_1         bash -c npm install && npm ...   Up                                                  
project_redis_1       docker-entrypoint.sh redis ...   Up      6379/tcp                                    
project_web-srv_1     nginx -g daemon off;             Up      0.0.0.0:44301->443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8080->80/tcp
project_wordpress_1   docker-entrypoint.sh apach ...   Up      443/tcp, 80/tcp                             

 Network status 
Network name                    Network subnet      Network gateway
project_network    172.100.112.0/24    172.100.112.1

Container name                      Container IPv4 address
project_wordpress_1    172.100.112.50/24
project_web-srv_1      172.100.112.30/24
project_app_1          172.100.112.40/24
project_redis_1        172.100.112.20/24
```

Hope somebody can help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try using curl and do a single request at a time, so you can see what redirects where. Then you should have an easier time figuring out where the redirect loop is.

Comment: Hey @HansKilian, curl -i just shows me the redirect: 


HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Wed, 02 Mar 2022 09:27:49 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Server: nginx
Location: https://kompassapp.de

<html>
<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>

Comment: To the same address or to another address. If it's to another address, then curl that and see what that gives you.

Comment: To the same address. You can check yourself, the URL is kompassapp.de

Comment: @HansKilian to make it more concrete:
when I do curl -i kompassapp.de or even when I do it with the server IP i get the 301 to the https address. which is in my view correct. I guess the problem is that the https is not responding as expected. 

I just set up a new server with the exact same code and the problem remains the same

Comment: When you do `curl -i kompassapp.de` you're hitting the http endpoint which, correctly, redirects you to the https address. What does the https address give you when you curl that?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @HansKilian

HTTP/2 301 
date: Thu, 03 Mar 2022 11:02:44 GMT
content-type: text/html
location: https://kompassapp.de
server: nginx

<html>
<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>